# How to define struct member as a sum of other members

Tags: c, struct

There are some questions similar to this (namely, [Define a struct with a member pointing to another member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33682473/define-a-struct-with-a-member-pointing-to-another-member)), but, given I'm complete noob at C, I cannot satisfy my question reading them, so I'm opening my own in the expectation of having some difference on it (if not, please point me to a proper question and close this as dupe).

What I'm trying to achieve is self explanatory:

```
typedef struct  {
    int goals_as_visitor;
    int goals_as_home;
    int total_goals = goals_as_visitor +  goals_as_home;
} team
```

I just want to store the `total_goals` struct member as permanently being the sum of the other two members.  The above code doesn't compile. I don't know if I just haven't found how to do it just yet, or if this is not possible.

Any guidance?

Comment: It can't be done in that way at all. You can't intialise struct fields as part of the struct definition. You can only set field values on variables not on type definitions. In terms of how best to do it, well that would depend on what your real problem is that you are trying to solve that makes you want to do this.

Comment: For example, you could define a function or macro that accepts a variable of that struct as well as the value of the first two fields as and then sets the third field based on those two field values. AFAIK, there is no automatic way in the C language to specify that one field is a relationship of some other fields.

Comment: Your last suggestion seems good. I'm trying to simply record results of some matches and determine which team is the winner. That might work. As dumb as it is, can you simply point out that this is not possible at all in C in a separate answer, so I don't leave this question open?

Comment: I'll provide an answer later if no-one else has any better way to do it. But note IMHO you really shouldn't be storing `total_goals` in the struct. Just derive it with a function call whenever it is needed: `int get_total_goals(team *t) { return t->goals_as_visitor +  t->goals_as_home; }`

Comment: I'm still trying to adapt from my background in Python / Scala to C, so some concepts are still mixed up for me. Thank you!

Comment: I second kaylum’s suggestion and generalize: When designing structs in C I believe it is best to (when possible) create them so they can never be in an “incorrect” state. Represent your data in it’s most minimal and robust form and leave incidental data (like sums) to be computed on the fly. Cache these values only when given strong reasons to do so. You may be surprised what a pleasure such structs are to work with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this is not possible. A C definition is roughly a definition of a storage space, no more. If you want to ensure that the field is always the sum of the first ones, then you need a discipline: each time you modify one of them, you'll have to modify the third. In this regard, OOP languages are better at this, C is too basic. Anyway you can try to use OOP style in C, something like:

```
typedef struct Team  {
    int goals_as_visitor;
    int goals_as_home;
    int total_goals;
} team;

void setGoalAsVisitor(struct Team *this,int value) {
    this->goals_as_visitor = value;
    this->total_goals = this->goals_as_visitor + this->goals_as_home;
}

...
setGoalAsVisitor(&team,666); // Roughly calling a method on team: aka team.setGoalAsVisitor(666) in Java style
...
```

and discipline yourself not to use the fields directly.

Note: you can hide many thing to enforce more the discipline, but alas C can let you make nasty things and violate the rules...

Answer (score 1):

Here you are just defining a structures by telling the compiler what members it contains.
To use this structure first you have to declare the structure and then and then only will a memory be allocated for that structure.
Structure members cannot be initialised with declaration.

Definition would be like this:

```
typedef struct  {
    int goals_as_visitor;
    int goals_as_home;
    int total_goals;
} team
```

and declaration will be like:

```
team red;
team blue;
```

Now the structure has some memory allocated, and structure members can be accessed using dot [.] operator.

e.g. `red.goals_as_visitor = 10;`

Here is a sample code may be this can help you out

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct  {
        int goals_as_visitor;
        int goals_as_home;
        int total_goals;
}team;
int main (void)
{
        team red ;
        red.goals_as_visitor=10; 
        red.goals_as_home = 5; 
        red.total_goals = red.goals_as_visitor + red.goals_as_home;

        printf("%d %d %d\n", red.goals_as_visitor, red.goals_as_home, red.total_goals);
        return 0;
}
```

You can refer below link for basics of structures [https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/structures-c/]

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible in c.But the total_goals will always sum of goals_as_visitor and goals_as_home.So the better way is to use total_goals as a function pointer like this

```
#include<stdio.h>


/*structure and elements*/

struct team;
int tot_g(struct team *sthis);
typedef int (*tot_gol)(struct team *sthis);

struct team
{
    int goals_as_visitor;
    int goals_as_home;
    const tot_gol total_goals;

}
const init={.goals_as_visitor=0,.goals_as_home=0,.total_goals=tot_g};

int tot_g(struct team *sthis)
{
   return (sthis->goals_as_visitor+sthis->goals_as_home);
}

typedef struct team team;

/*structure and elements*/

int main()
{
     team p=init;
     p.goals_as_home=5;
     p.goals_as_visitor=5;
     printf("%d",p.total_goals(&p));
}
```

You must always initialize when a team object is defined with init.

Or

The simple way to do this is using a function like

```
#include<stdio.h>

typedef struct  {
    int goals_as_visitor;
    int goals_as_home;
} team;

int total_goals(team var)
{
    return (var.goals_as_home+var.goals_as_visitor);
}

int main()
{
     team p;
     p.goals_as_home=5;
     p.goals_as_visitor=5;
     printf("%d",total_goals(p));
}
```

You can use total_goals function parameter as const pointer also.